# jQuery slider where the image that is sliding is the background of a div

Tags: jquery, image, slider, transparent

I am trying to get a basic jQuery image slider working, however this is different from previous sliders I've done. See this image:

[example http://puu.sh/34q0h.png](http://puu.sh/34q0h.png)

http://puu.sh/34q0h.png <-- link if you can't see the image

The image that's sliding is going to the the background of the header itself. I've tried all the solutions I can think of but none of them allow the image to go **behind** the transparent menu that you can see above.

Am I even going about this correctly? Should I be modifying the css `background` property, or sliding actual `<img>`'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the nav absolutely positioned in a block with the slider and use the z-index on the nav to bring it above.

Answer (score 0):

Dude the above image is not visible....
BTW, there must be some issue regarding the z-axis... Try playing with z-Index(css)